# Case insensitive search and replace in array bash array

Tags: arrays, bash, replace, case-insensitive

I learned [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/bash-array-tutorial/) about search and replace in array using array.

It goes like this.

```
declare -a Unix=('Debian' 'Red hat' 'Ubuntu' 'Suse' 'Fedora');
echo ${Unix[@]/Red*/}

# Output will be
Debian Ubuntu Suse Fedora
```

In the above snippet, flag `a` was used to do this with case-insensitive search. i.e I want to search with "red" instead "Red".

Comment: `declare -a` doesn't have anything to do with case sensitivity; it means "declare this to be an array"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put `r` and `R` inside a character class `[]`.

```
$ declare -a Unix=('Debian' 'red hat' 'Ubuntu' 'Suse' 'Fedora');
$ echo ${Unix[@]/[rR]ed*/}
Debian Ubuntu Suse Fedora
```

Comment: so this is for just one word, what if I need to do it for all the words(Just assume I have to). 

I will be writing

$ echo ${Unix[@]/[a-z][A-Z]ed*/}

??

Comment: use `${Unix[@]/[a-zA-Z]ed*/}`, this would remove elem which has  `red`, Red, sed, fed, etc.

Comment: Thanks, It means there are no special switch just basic regex. :)

Comment: @tollboy: They are not regex. They are bash patterns. (Which is why you write `*` and not `.*`, for example.) You can make pattern matching case insensitive under some circumstances with `shopt nocaseglob` and `shopt nocasematch` but neither apply to the search-and-replace parameter expansion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `printf` and `grep -i` here:

```
printf "%s\n" "${Unix[@]}" | grep -iv Red
Debian
Ubuntu
Suse
Fedora

printf "%s\n" "${Unix[@]}" | grep -iv red
Debian
Ubuntu
Suse
Fedora
```

---

**Update:** To get output in single line:

```
printf "%s\n" "${Unix[@]}" | grep -iv red | tr '\n' ' '; echo
Debian Ubuntu Suse Fedora
```